# php restructue an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I'd like to restructure but I can't figure out to do it.

Currently my array looks like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [band] => Coilguns
            [date] => 2018-03-14T00:00:00Z
            [location] => Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.
            [city] => Tubingen
            [country] => Germany
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [band] => Coilguns
            [date] => 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z
            [location] => Unter Deck
            [city] => Munich
            [country] => Germany
        )
)
```

I want it to look like :

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [band] => Coilguns
      [dates] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [date] => 2018-03-14T00:00:00Z
              [location] => Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.
              [city] => Tubingen
              [country] => Germany
            )
          [1] => Array
            (
              [date] => 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z
              [location] => Unter Deck
              [city] => Munich
              [country] => Germany
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Basicaly, I'd like to an array of bands, each band's array containing an array of dates. Does it make sense?

Comment: How can a date contain city or country ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something along the lines of

```
    $array = Array(
        Array("band"=> "Coilguns", "date"=> "2018-03-14T00:00:00Z", "location"=> "Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.", "city"=> "Tubingen", "country"=> "Germany"),
        Array("band"=> "Coilguns", "date"=> "2018-03-15T00:00:00Z", "location"=> "Unter Deck", "city"=> "Munich", "country"=> "Germany"),
    );

    $result = Array();

    $bands = array_unique(array_column($array, 'band')); //makes an array of all different "bands"
    print_r($bands);
    foreach($bands as $band) {
        $dates = Array();
        foreach($array as $row) {
            if($row['band'] != $band) continue; // skip if the band is different
            unset($row['band']);
            $dates[] = $row;

        }
        $result[] = Array(
            "band" => $band, 
            "dates" => $dates
        );
    }
    print_r($result);
    /*
    Array
    (
         [0] => Array
              (
                    [band] => Coilguns
                    [dates] => Array
                         (
                              [0] => Array
                                    (
                                         [date] => 2018-03-14T00:00:00Z
                                         [location] => Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.
                                         [city] => Tubingen
                                         [country] => Germany
                                    )

                              [1] => Array
                                    (
                                         [date] => 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z
                                         [location] => Unter Deck
                                         [city] => Munich
                                         [country] => Germany
                                    )

                         )

              )

    )
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to sort the dates per band name. So I suggest the following structure:

```
Array
(
  [Coilguns] => Array
    (
      .. dates ..
    )
)
```

You can try this code:

```
<?php
    $aOriginal = array (
        array ( "band"=> "Coilguns", "date"=> "2018-03-14T00:00:00Z", "location"=> "Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.", "city"=> "Tubingen", "country"=> "Germany" ),
        array ( "band"=> "Coilguns", "date"=> "2018-03-15T00:00:00Z", "location"=> "Unter Deck", "city"=> "Munich", "country"=> "Germany" ),
    ); // Your original array as stated in your post.

    $aSortedArray = array ( );

    foreach ( $aOriginal as $aTemp )
    {
        if ( ! isset ( $aSortedArray[$aTemp['band']] ) )
        {
            $aSortedArray[$aTemp['band']] = array ( );
        }

        $aSortedArray[$aTemp['band']][] = $aTemp;
    }

    var_dump ( $aSortedArray );
?>
```

This will produce:

```
Array
(
    [Coilguns] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [band] => Coilguns
            [date] => 2018-03-14T00:00:00Z
            [location] => Jugendzentrum Epplehaus e.V.
            [city] => Tubingen
            [country] => Germany
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [band] => Coilguns
            [date] => 2018-03-15T00:00:00Z
            [location] => Unter Deck
            [city] => Munich
            [country] => Germany
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = [];
array_map(function ($band, $item) use (&$result) {
    $result[$band]['band'] = $band;
    unset($item['band']);
    $result[$band]['dates'][] = $item;
}, array_column($array, 'band'), $array);

$result = array_values($result);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/195ebf8f2f6ac1ebc6fd8a8687d9b2b60e4513fd).